# alexa skills kit developer console test simulator not generating IntentRequest event

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I created a skill thru the developer console. The skill calls my amazon lambda service.  The test simulator creates the  Launch Request just  fine and that comes back with what i expect.  Then when i try to test an utterance the IntentRequest never shows in the console logs in the  cloud watch in the service.

Below is my intent json code

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "hello world",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "TestIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "hello donna",
                        "hello world",
                        "say hello world",
                        "to say hello world"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.PauseIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.ResumeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my lambda js code

```
/**

 Copyright 2016 Brian Donohue.

*/

'use strict';

// Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
// etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    try {
        //console.log("event.session.application.applicationId=" + event.session.application.applicationId);
        console.log("event.request.type ===" + event.request.type);


        /**
         * Uncomment this if statement and populate with your skill's application ID to
         * prevent someone else from configuring a skill that sends requests to this function.
         */

        //     if (event.session.application.applicationId !== "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.05aecccb3-1461-48fb-a008-822ddrt6b516") {
        //         context.fail("Invalid Application ID");
        //      }

        if (event.session.new) {
            onSessionStarted({ requestId: event.request.requestId }, event.session);
        }

        if (event.request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            onLaunch(event.request,
                event.session,
                function callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    context.succeed(buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
        } else if (event.request.type === "IntentRequest") {
            onIntent(event.request,
                event.session,
                function callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    context.succeed(buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
        } else if (event.request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
            context.succeed();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        context.fail("Exception: " + e);
    }
};

/**
 * Called when the session starts.
 */
function onSessionStarted(sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    console.log("onSessionStarted requestId=" + sessionStartedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    // add any session init logic here
}

/**
 * Called when the user invokes the skill without specifying what they want.
 */
function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log("onLaunch requestId=" + launchRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var cardTitle = "Hello, World!"
    var speechOutput = "You can tell Hello, World! to say Hello, World!"
    callback(session.attributes,
        buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", true));
}

/**
 * Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
 */
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log("onIntent requestId=" + intentRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var intent = intentRequest.intent,
        intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

    // dispatch custom intents to handlers here
    if (intentName == 'TestIntent') {
        handleTestRequest(intent, session, callback);
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid intent";
    }
}

/**
 * Called when the user ends the session.
 * Is not called when the skill returns shouldEndSession=true.
 */
function onSessionEnded(sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    console.log("onSessionEnded requestId=" + sessionEndedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    // Add any cleanup logic here
}

function handleTestRequest(intent, session, callback) {
    callback(session.attributes,
        buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("Hello, Donna World!", "", "true"));
}

// ------- Helper functions to build responses -------

function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        card: {
            type: "Simple",
            title: title,
            content: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
    return {
        version: "1.0",
        sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
        response: speechletResponse
    };
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tested it on Alexa skill builder's test section? And what was the output when you tested it on aws lambda?